# How to instanciate dependant type

Tags: c++

The title is definitively not the best, please help me to improve it.

The following code works. I would like to replace the macro with regular c++ template code, but I don’t see how to do it.

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <utility>


struct A {
    struct X{};
    struct Y{};
    struct Z{};
};

struct B {
    struct X{};
    struct Y{};
    struct Z{};
};

// A and B have the same inner struct X, Y, Z

enum class AB {
    a,
    b,
};

#define access(ab_, Attribute) \
    [] (AB ab) -> std::variant<A::Attribute, B::Attribute> { \
        if (ab == AB::a) { \
            return A::Attribute{}; \
        } else { \
            return B::Attribute{}; \
        } \
    }(ab_)

int main() {
    AB ab = AB::a; // I get somehow a runtime value of type AB
    // And I want to create A::X or B::X depending of the runtime value of ab
    std::variant<A::X, B::X> v = access(ab, X);
}
```

---

Instead of using a macro, I’d like to write something like this

```cpp
template <class Attribute>
std::variant<A::Attribute, B::Attribute> access2(AB ab) {
    if (ab == AB::a) {
        return A::template Attribute{};
    } else {
        return B::template Attribute{};
    }
}
```

but I can’t make it work (and I’m not sure it’s possible).

---

EDIT: I realized that in my use case, `X` can be default constructed, but `Y` has a non-trivial constructor (I need to give it a `std::string`). I know how to make the macro variadic, and would like to be able to do the same with normal C++ template code.

Comment: You should probably elaborate your specific use case for this in 1st place, and what you actually need to achieve. As is your question sounds like an xy-problem for me. Best asking for how to create generic mapper classes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I’m writing a parser. The first thing I’m extracting is the type of node (either `A` or `B`), so a runtime value. Then I parse some attribute, and I want to return the exact type of the attribute (so either `A::Node` or `B::Node`). I don’t think I have an X/Y problem here. ––– Do you have any link on "how to create a generic mapper class" in C++, I think that it’s exactly what I want to do but my duckduckgo-fu is failing me ––– Without this `access` macro, my code is full of `if (ab == AB::a) { return A::X; } else { return B::X; }`

Comment: You may want to consider using [Spirit X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html) to facilitate your parsing.  It looks a bit daunting at first, because it expresses EBNF within the constraints of the overloadable C++ operators.